# Running a Spark Application in Intellij 14.1.3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-14

I am trying to run a Spark Application written in Scala in Intellij 14.1.3.The scala sdk is scala-sdk-2.11.6. I get the following error when I execute my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$.empty()Lscala/collection/immutable/HashSet;
at akka.actor.ActorCell$.<init>(ActorCell.scala:336)
at akka.actor.ActorCell$.<clinit>(ActorCell.scala)
at akka.actor.RootActorPath.$div(ActorPath.scala:159)
at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.<init>(ActorRefProvider.scala:464)
at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.<init>(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:78)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:73)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree1$1(ActorSystem.scala:584)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:577)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:118)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1837)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1828)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:223)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:163)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:269)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:272)
at LRParquetProcess$.main(LRParquetProcess.scala:9)
at LRParquetProcess.main(LRParquetProcess.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

My pom.xml is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ParquetGeneration</groupId>
<artifactId>ParquetGeneration</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
<hadoop.version>2.7.0</hadoop.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-app</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Spark is not compatible with scala 2.11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to scala 2.10, will be better at the moment

Comment: Thank you Thomas. Can you tell me how I can move to 2.10 ? Will be really helpful.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested you should try 2.10.x.

Install 2.10.x and set the relevant environment variables to use it. Since you already have a project go to File -> Project Structure -> Global Libraries and remove 2.11.x. Then add 2.10.x by pressing the '+' -> Scala SDK -> Browse and select the 2.10.x folder you installed earlier.

The scala version requirements are specified in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/).

Comment: Meanwhile i got difference error, but this works, i know that my app work on scala 2.11, but my env was 2.13. Thanks, it was pain in the neck. The error was scala.collection.mutable.Set$.apply.blablabla